# Unable to locate required content from html <section> : Python BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scrapping this [website](https://www.met.ie/) for weather forecasts. Its html is quite nested and i am not able to retrieve the required contents. The section i want to scrape is mentioned below:

[image: Section to be scraped]

To fetch required tags for html of this section, i am using following approach:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import uuid
import csv
import dateutil.parser as parser


class met():
    def __init__(self):
        global homePage
        global downloadDir
        global filname
        downloadDir = ""
        uFileName = str(uuid.uuid4())
        filname = downloadDir + uFileName + ".csv"
        homePage = requests.get("https://www.met.ie/")

    def pageHtml(self):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(homePage.content, 'html.parser')
        titleList = soup.findAll('title')
        for div in soup.find_all("div"):
            for section in div.find_all('section', class_ = "container hourly-forecast mb-5",id = "24HourForecast"):
                #print(section)
                for div1 in section.find_all("div"):
                    print(div1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    objCall = met()
    objCall.pageHtml()
```

After running this code, i am able to retrieve tags but all those tags are from the prior container. Can anybody help me follow right approach here, Thanks

Comment: The content are heavily dynamic. The portion your script can find out is this `<section id="24HourForecast" class="container hourly-forecast mb-5">
    <div class="hp_title_wrapper my-5">
        <div class="hp_title">
<span>
    <h2>24 Hour Forecast &nbsp;</h2>
</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>`. However, this is obviously not you wanna source data from. Try using their api or any browser simulator.

Comment: Btw, [this is the api](https://prodapi.metweb.ie/weather/details/53.375715/-6.269870) leading to the required data which you can make use of.

Comment: @SIM you are right and this `<div class="hp_title_wrapper my-5"> <div class="hp_title"> <span>` is part of some other section. what do you mean by browser simulation? Beside i think they don't have an API.

Comment: @SIM how did you find it ? i have been looking for it

Comment: What I meant by browser simulator is selenium, e.t.c. I found out that api link using chrome dev tools in it's network tab.

Comment: ok, i hope the API works and i also found some information without images. Thank  you